# Spark writing extra rows when saving to CSV

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I wrote a file to parquet containing 1,000,000 rows. 
When I read the parquet file back, the result is 1,000,000 rows.

```
df = spark.read.parquet(parquet_path)
df.count()
>>> 1000000
```

When I save the parquet file to CSV, read it back, then count the rows, the output is 1,000,365.

```
df.write.csv(csv_path, sep='\t', header=False, mode='overwrite')
df_csv = spark.read.csv(csv_path, sep='\t', header=False)
df_csv.count()
>>> 1000365
```

Why is Spark adding the extra columns to dataset? 
I tried a variety of separators and both `False` and `True` for the header. 
I also tried to coalesce and repartition but the same number keeps appearing.

Does anyone know why Spark would add the extra columns?

Comment: This can happen if you have newlines in data. could you try `write.csv(..., quoteAll=True)` and `read.csv(..., multiLine=True)` and see what happens?

Comment: Adding `multiLine=True` solved my problem, @Emma. If you could kindly write your response as the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurs while reading csv files which includes newlines. The newlines will split into multiple records by default.

To read the multiline csv correctly, you need to first make sure the field is properly quoted.

```
1,short text,"long text with newline\n quote within this field should be \"escaped\"."
```

Although double quote is the default, the quote char could be other characters than double quote.

Check the default csv options here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html

Then, when you read this csv including the newline (\n). You need to add `multiLine=True` option.

```py
spark.read.csv(csv_path, multiLine=True)

# or

spark.read.option('multiLine', True).csv(csv_path)
```