# How to properly import CSV files with PySpark

Tags: dataframe, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I know, that one can load files with PySpark for RDD's using the following commands:

```
sc = spark.sparkContext
someRDD = sc.textFile("some.csv")
```

or for dataframes:

```
spark.read.options(delimiter=',') \
  .csv("some.csv")
```

My `file` is a .csv with 10 columns, seperated by `','` . However, the very last column contains some text, that also has a lot of `","`. Splitting by `","` will result in different column sizes for each row and moreover, I do not have the whole text in one column.
I am just looking for a good way to load a `.csv` file into a dataframe that has multiple `","` at the very last index.

Maybe there is way to only split on the first `n` columns? Because it is guaranteed, that all columns before the text column are only seperated by one `","`. Interestingly, using `pd.read_csv` does not cause this issue! So far my workaround has been to load the file with

```
csv = pd.read_csv("some.csv", delimiter=",")
csv_to_array = csv.values.tolist()
df = createDataFrame(csv_to_array)
```

which is not a pretty solution. Moreover, it did not allow me to use some schema on my dataframe.

Comment: Can you change the separator or add a escape character to the commas that are between two separators?

Comment: I doubt that this would be practical. The file has million of rows

Comment: The answer you're looking for is to *quote* all columns that contain the file delimiter. [Look at quoting and quotechar parameters of Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). This is primarily one read why CSV format is not recommended for data analysis.

Comment: Could you share the sample data in a plain text?   If it works with `read_csv`, then could you also try adding `multiLine=True` for spark?

Comment: I still prefer to see the sample data but prematurely speaking, this might be your case.    https://stackoverflow.com/a/72143101/2956135

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't correct the input file, then you can try to load it as text then split the values to get the desired columns. Here's an example:

###### input file

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0,12,121
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0,12,121
```

###### read and parse

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

nb_cols = 5

df = spark.read.text("file.csv")

df = df.withColumn(
    "values",
    F.split("value", ",")
).select(
    *[F.col("values")[i].alias(f"col_{i}") for i in range(nb_cols)],
    F.array_join(F.expr(f"slice(values, {nb_cols + 1}, size(values))"), ",").alias(f"col_{nb_cols}")
)

df.show()
#+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------------------+
#|col_0|col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|              col_5|
#+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------------------+
#|    1|    2|    3|    4|    5|6,7,8,9,10,0,12,121|
#|    1|    2|    3|    4|    5|6,7,8,9,10,0,12,121|
#+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------------------+
```

Comment: This is sort of what I am looking for. However, how can I just use the last column `(nb_cols + 1)` as one string?

Comment: @kklaw that's what `array_join` do in the above example. the last column is a of type string