# Why the different number of entries from spark.read.csv and pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

What could be the reason for the different number of entries by 1) spark.read.csv and 2) pandas read_csv? Thanks!

*1) spark.read.csv*

```
!pip install pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]"))

spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .getOrCreate()

url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gracenzmy/experiment/main/Womens%20Clothing%20E-Commerce%20Reviews.csv'

from pyspark import SparkFiles

spark.sparkContext.addFile(url)

df = spark.read.csv(SparkFiles.get("Womens Clothing E-Commerce Reviews.csv"), header=True).drop('_c0')

df.count(),len(df.columns) # (26928, 10)
```

*2) pandas read_csv*

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gracenzmy/experiment/main/Womens%20Clothing%20E-Commerce%20Reviews.csv',index_col=0)

df.shape # (23486, 10)
```

Comment: it might be due to this => https://stackoverflow.com/a/72143101/2956135

Comment: Thanks @Emma but setting multiline=True gives (24149, 10) which is incorrect. read_csv from pandas i.e. (23486, 10) is the correct one.

Comment: try adding `escape='"'` as well.  It looks like it is using double quote as escape character which is not the default escape character (\\)

Comment: Thanks @Emma! It is correct now as you advised. By the way, where can I get a more informative documentation on read.csv? Because I find https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv not as helpful.

Comment: Does this help https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html?

Comment: The `csv` module was the same as `pandas`. And just for fun, the raw line count is 28228, so spark figured out some of the embedded newlines.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) pandas doesn't count Null/NaN rows.

> pandas.DataFrame.count DataFrame.count(axis=0, level=None,
> numeric_only=False)[source] Count non-NA cells for each column or row.
>
> The values None, NaN, NaT, and optionally numpy.inf (depending on
> pandas.options.mode.use_inf_as_na) are considered NA.

So its possible you got null rows in your dataset and pandas has ignored these rows and since Spark doesn't ignore null rows, you are seeing more rows. For consistancy sake you may try dropping null rows using dropna() method. `df = df.dropna()` should do the trick. Do it for both spark and pandas dataframes for consistency. This is standard practice which we follow in data cleaning process.

Comment: The pandas count is already less than the spark count. If there were rows to drop, it would diverge more.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the answer for more clarity. My advice was to apply the method to spark dataframe which will remove null rows and match with pandas df.